# Installing original OS on Samsung s3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing, operating-system

Is it possible to install Google's original OS without all the manufacturer-added bloatware that comes with the device?

Is there a chance that I would ruin the phone and/or not be able to get it to work as it used to if I don't like it for some reason?

Are there any important features that I would miss out if I had to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have some custom ROMs, but if you want just to remove the bloatware, I would just root my device, uninstall those bloatwares and if possible unroot again.

Some rooting methods does permit to unroot and some do not.  Even in latter case all that has happened is just you had rooted your device and still have your original ROM.

Comment: I also like the look that comes with the nexus, but that's secondary really.

How would I root it? And I assume rooting will void warranty?

Comment: I just made a Google search and found http://www.androidauthority.com/galaxy-s3-gt-i9300-root-clockworkmod-recovery-95849 explaining it step by step. Some manufacturers does not provide warranty on rooted device. But rooting is not illegal and some manufacturers permit, though they are literally countable.  After rooting, you will be able to install any ROM and that includes the original ROM that was unrooted. So, in case of problems (of certain kind) you can restore the original ROM.

Comment: This page says http://blog.everyonehere.info/how-to-unroot-samsung-galaxy-s3 how to unroot your S3.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help.

One question, if I had to unroot it and restore the original ROM, there'd probably some trace of my tampering with the device anyway would there? That will probably be enough for Samsung to void the warranty.

Comment: No absolutely not. However, Samsung has different versions of ROM for different regions. You can see your ROM in Settings->About phone. If you can get the same ROM type instead of that said in unroot procedure, there will be no difference at all.

Comment: @Narayanan Wont there be a counter which will be incremented when we flash our phone with some other ROM ?

Comment: I haven't heard of such counters. As a far as my device LG P500 is concerned, I had flashed more than 5 different ROMS, each several times, the total should at least should have exceeded 20 times - to best of my knowledge.  Just learnt now that Samsung seems to have such counters. And there are minds to provide solution for that as well :) http://www.shetalksandroid.com/2012/03/how-to-reset-sgs2-flash-counter-and.html